# c# docx load xml from string xml

Tags: c#, docx, xceed

I have created a program to read a file as array of bytes. The program is consuming word files by using docx library from Xceed. What I want to do is to recreate the parsed docx file from array of bytes.

To bytes:

```
var doc = Docx.Load("afile.docx");
...
return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(doc.Xml.Document.ToString());
```

Parse:

```
var doc = Docx.Create("anotherFile.docx");
var document = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes({--returned bytes--}); <-- document is string with xml
```

**How to save the document like the original?**
I'm getting only blank file without any content.

Comment: That is not going to work. You need to load the whole `doc` into a `MemoryStream`, which you can get the byte array from. You can then load the byte array into a different memory stream. Without knowing too much about the Xceed docx library, I'm going to guess it has a way of creating a document instance from a stream.

Comment: I've never used that library but as one might guess it [has a `Load` method](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-document-libraries-for-net/Xceed.Words.NET~Xceed.Words.NET.DocX~Load(Stream).html)

Answer (score 0):

See this document [BinaryWriter](http://csharp.net-informations.com/file/csharp-binarywriter.htm)

bWriter.Writebytes(bytearray);

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var doc = DocX.Load("afile.docx"))
{
    //here modify
    doc.SaveAs("anotherFile.docx");
}
```